# What is the alternative to using Storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone

So I'm just starting developing an iPhone application and I've been told to not use Storyboard. I've read that the alternative is using xib files - can anyone recommend good tutorials using xib files?

Thanks

Comment: Was telling you not to use storyboards a suggestion, or are you actually forbidden to use them? If so, why?

Comment: I'm forbidden to use them because multiple people will work on this app later and I guess storyboards might make that more difficult. I think also because we want more control over the user interface. And I guess we're crazy.

Comment: Use xibs, one per UIViewController, or just create the UI in code. Either will work. Both have advantages/disadvantages. If multiple people are working on the user interface simultaneously, it is definitely better to use xibs or raw code than storyboards.

Comment: is there an advantage to using xibs vs raw code?

Comment: There are some valid reasons to use or not use Storyboards. It totally depends on how you intend to design/build the app. Is this a fresh code base for a new app? or are you going to reuse a lot of code from an existing code base?

Comment: @praks5432  No, no special advantage. Storyboards simple write some of the code to handle navigating from one view to another. You are still using nibs/xibs technology underneath. You still use the Interface Builder features in the same way, write much of the same kind of code, but don't have to write some of that navigation code. But there's no free lunch – you can get yourself painted into a corner when you want a different navigation flow.

Comment: @praks5432 xibs give you a visual representation of how the UI will look like, and will let you add most of the UI elements without adding a lot of lines of code. That said, if your UI elements are dynamic (in terms of position and size, based on state of the app), those UI elements are better created programatically

Comment: ahhh I see. So if I were to use interface builder as opposed to storyboard, would that make it easier for multiple people to work on the same app and for me to break apart parts of the app for reuse in other apps?

Comment: It's easier and faster to lay out a bunch of controls in a xib. However, we often use raw code for a few reasons, some of them no longer relevant. It used to be easier to localize raw code than xibs. Xcode's xib editor in Xcode 5 was pretty buggy for a while, crashing regularly. We can view subversion diffs and blame easier for code. Handling slightly different layouts for portrait and landscape is easier in code in my opinion. It's really a personal or team preference more than anything.

Answer (score 4):

Storyboards are a relatively new feature to Xcode and Cocoa. Arrived with [Xcode 4.2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_2.html).

[image]

For decades (see [history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder)), [NeXTSTEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeXTSTEP)/[OpenStep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStep)/[Cocoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_%28API%29) programmers have been building individual nib/xib files, loading them with ViewControllers. When the user does something to cause the app to move to the next nib/xib, the current view controller instantiates another view controller that loads its desired nib/xib. That new view controller is then shown on screen.

Storyboards are not magic. They just reduce your programming load a bit, handling that loading and displaying of one view controller from another. They still use the same nib/xib technology underneath, you are just less aware of it. Think of a Storyboard as an automatically managed collection of xibs. A superset of nib/xib, rather than a replacement.

In iOS, we often get the new view controller on the screen by pushing it onto a [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s stack. The *Back* button automatically appears to close the current view controller and return to the previous one.

There are pros and cons to Storyboards. For relatively simple apps with a certain flow of views, they can be handy.

But there are reasons to not use them. One reason is if moving from view to view is somewhat arbitrary and not easily laid out in a Storyboard. Another reason is that some views are more easily done programatically on-the-fly rather without defining any nib/xib. Typically such views have only one, or very few, components. UIListView and UIWebView are two examples of single widgets that may fill the screen and can therefore be more conveniently created in code.

Tutorial and books abound. Some show both Storyboard and non-Storyboard ways of doing things. Look for some older iOS 5 or 6 books to see more non-Storyboard ways.

Some new articles and Apple docs may push Storyboard because they are the new fresh thing. I suggest taking a more measured approach. Rather than saying Storyboards are the greatest thing or saying Storyboard are terrible, consider them as yet another tool. Sometimes you may want to use them, sometimes they not fit your needs optimally. Also you can mix them, doing part of your app with a Storyboard, and part without.

Comment: Great answer but I wouldn't call storyboards "very new".  They came out two years ago in the same release as ARC.

Comment: @BrianNickel Well, in terms of the history of Xcode and XIB they are very new ;).

Comment: @borrrden In terms of iOS development they've been around forever. :)  To me "very new" stokes a tone of being unproven, untested.  There've been two years and two major iOS releases since, so hopefully that's no longer the case.  I think the intent of the statement was to convey that a lot of developers have been doing it different ways for a long time, making them wary and opinionated about it.  That's probably why the OP heard not to use them.  I think they way the sentence is worded detracts from that message.

Comment: @BrianNickel Yes, and in OS X development even longer.  I can see how the tone sounds that way though.  I don't prefer storyboards either, so I didn't pay as much attention to the tone as I probably should have.  Although I would have chosen relatively new for my wording. In the comments OP mentions the reason is because multiple people will be working on the app.  I can totally understand that.  Storyboards are a pain in the ass to merge.

Comment: I added a timeline chart to show that, in the context of the original poster's question, Storyboard is indeed a "very new" feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can use storyboards (.storyboard files), use older interface builder (.xib files) or do everything programmatically.

I recommend to use storyboards, makes many things easier and less writing, storyboard is similar to interface builder and my opinion, when creating iOS app, it's better choice than older interface builder. And you still can do many things programmatically, e.g. change properties of objects created in storyboard etc.

So if someone says, don't use storyboards, it's his/her opinion and I suggest that you try it out and make your own opinion about it.